# How do I use Eval() to reference values in a SortedDictionary in an asp Repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, sorteddictionary

I thought I was clever to switch from the memory intensive DataView to SortedDictionary as a memory efficient sortable data structure.  Now I have no idea how get the key and value out of the datasource in the <%# or Eval() expressions.

```
SortedDictionary<int, string> data = RetrieveNames();
rCurrentTeam.DataSource = data;
rCurrentTeam.DataBind();

<asp:Repeater ID="rNames" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("what?") %>' />
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use either of these two options:

```
<%# Eval("Key") %>
<!-- or -->
<%# Eval("Value") %>
```

depending on whether you need the key or the value from the dictionary.

This makes sense if you think about how data binding works.  Data binding is a process by which a control takes an enumerable sequence, iterates that sequence, and uses reflection to extract values from each item in the sequence based on properties that the item exposes.

Since `SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>` implements the `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` interface you know that the repeater will enumerate a sequence of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` objects, binding to each one in turn.

If you look at the properties that are exposed by the [`KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e2wb99w.aspx) class you will see just two: `Key` and `Value`.  Since they are public properties you can `Eval` them and the control will be able to extract the values that they encapsulate.

Comment: Great answer, I'm wondering how do controls that databind know which IEnumerable list to utilize when objects are bound to it? Meaning, what if I wanted to make my own controls to be databound. Is there some kind of assembly property that makes a certain IEnumable member the 'default' for databinding?